# DateProperty turns into datetimeProperty during csv import

Tags: python, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to import data from a csv file into my local gae datastore. Basically it works fine but for some reason I end up with a datetimeProperty instead of only a datePoperty.
After the import all date values contain a time information (e.g. 2014-11-21 00:00:00).

Does anyone know why?

Model:

```
class DaxValue(db.Model):
    date = db.DateProperty(required=True)
    close = db.FloatProperty()
    prev_close = db.FloatProperty()
    high = db.FloatProperty()
    low = db.FloatProperty()
    opn = db.FloatProperty()
    isTradingDay = db.BooleanProperty()
    popDate = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

Code to import the csv:

```
def pop_db():

    with open('table.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(reader)

        for row in reader:

            date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d"))).date()
            open1 = float(row[1])
            high = float(row[2])
            low = float(row[3])
            close = float(row[4])
            adj_close = float(row[6])

            query = "SELECT * FROM DaxValue WHERE date = DATE('%s')" % str(date)
            q = db.GqlQuery(query)
            dax_value = q.get()

            if not dax_value:
                dax_value = DaxValue(date=date, open=open1, close=close, high=high, low=low, isTradingDay=True)

            else:
                dax_value.close = close
                dax_value.opn = open1
                dax_value.high = high
                dax_value.low = low
                dax_value.popDate = datetime.now()
                dax_value.isTradingDay = True
                dax_value.prev_close = adj_close

            dax_value.put()
```

I struggle with this query which returns None even though there is an entry stored for that day...

```
yesterday = (datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
query = "SELECT * FROM DaxValue WHERE date = DATE('%s')" % str(yesterday.date())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google stores all date properties and time properties internally as datetimes.  Below is an excerpt from [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses):

> class DateProperty(verbose_name=None, auto_now=False,
>   auto_now_add=False, ...) A date without a time of day; see
>   DateTimeProperty for more information.
>
> Value type: datetime.date; converted internally to datetime.datetime

I use both date and datetime properties and this hasn't caused a problem for me even though it seems odd to store them all as datetimes.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for this information. I've seen it before but wasn't really aware of the meaning. Besides that i do have a problem when i try to query a specific date. I've added my example at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: Please open a new question for new issues, and refrain from adding new problems to existing questions.